# Process cannot find the correct file location

Tags: java, c++, mysql, netbeans, processbuilder

I created C++ programs that is tasked to back up and restore a database in MySQL. These C++ programs both use two folders, namely, `readerCode` and `saves`. The `readerCode` contains text files (or scripts) that contains command in mysql. The `saves` folder is where the back up is stored. I stored the programs and the folders in `C:\AwesomeDatabase\ext`.

When I run the programs through cmd, the command ran successfully. It generates a .sql file in saves folder. But when I run it through my Java program using process builder, the java program can run the executable programs (for back up and restore), but the C++ programs cannot find the file it is task to locate. Thanks in advance!

Code fragment from **Process.java**

```
private void menuItemBackupActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try {
        String cmd [] = {"\"C:\\AwesomeDatabase\\ext\\DBBackup.exe\"", "-d"};
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder ("\"C:\\AwesomeDatabase\\ext\\DBBackup.exe\"", "-d");
        builder.redirectErrorStream (true);
        Process p = builder.start();
        java.io.BufferedReader r = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while (true) {
            line = r.readLine();
            if (line == null) { break; }
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (java.io.IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println ("Fatal Error! Back up file not found!\n" + ioe);
    }

}
```

Yeah so java will start a process when `menuItemBackup` is clicked. So here's my **DBBackup.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

#include "backup_head.h"

using namespace std;

//void secureBackup (void);
void normalBackup (void);

int 
main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

    if (argc > 1) {
        if (strcmp (argv [1], "-s") == false) {
            //secureBackup();
        } else if (strcmp (argv [1], "-d") == false) {
            normalBackup();
        } else {
            cout << "Invalid Command Line Arguments!" << endl;
            Sleep (500);
        }
    } else {
        cout << "Invalid Process Spawn!" << endl;
        Sleep (500);
    }

    return (0);
}

void 
normalBackup (void) 
{

    /* Fetch Location Variables */
    Program_Path        progpath    =   "";
    Change_Directory    cd          =   "CD";

    /* Back Up Variables */
    Program_Name    progdump    =   "mysqldump";
    Database_Name   dbname      =   "sampledb";
    Directory_Name  dirName     =   "saves";
    Dump_Name       dumpName    =   "BackUpNow";
    Username        username    =   "root";
    Password        password    =   "root";

    /* Delete Old Back Up */
    Command         delCommand  =   "DEL";
    File_Name       file        =   "DBBackUp";
    File_Directory  fileDir     =   "saves";

    /* Commands */
    _getcwd (progpath, sizeof (progpath));
    _chdir (progpath);
    SetCurrentDirectory (progpath);
    Command redir = cd + " " + "\"" + string(progpath) + "\"";
    Command backup = progdump + " " + "-u " + username + " " + "-p" + password + " " + dbname + " > " + dirName + "/" + dumpName + ".sql";
    Command delOld = delCommand + " \"" + fileDir + "/" + file + ".sql\"";

    cout << "Back Up process is on-going..." << endl << "Please wait for a moment..." << endl;
    Sleep (500);
    system (redir.c_str());
    system (delOld.c_str());
    system (backup.c_str());
    cout << "Back Up Completed Successfully!";
    Sleep (500);

    return;
}
```

`Program_Path` is a type definition of `char [99]`. The rest of the 'weird' data types are just strings (I used `typedef` to them to identify which variable should be used in a specific use). My java program will be run on `NetBeans Projects` folder on `Documents` folder. When I run my project in the NetBeans, this will be the output:

```
Back Up process is on-going... 
Please wait for a moment... 
The system cannot find the path specified. 
The system cannot find the path specified. 
Back Up Completed Successfully!
```

Comment: The problem is that the [`system`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx) function creates a new process, and run the `cd` command in just that process. Read about the [`SetCurrentDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WIN32 system call or the [`_chdir`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7fwze1.aspx) CRT function instead.

Comment: I tried and included in the code above the functions you added. It didn't fix the problem BUT thank you so much! I found out that the Java program runs the C++ program from the `NetBeansProjects\<project name>` so the C++ program cannot find the correct path itself.